# React state hook, toogle class, why are both elements getting the "active" class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hope you can help me.

Why are both my li elements getting the active class applied to it?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("false");

  const creditValues = [
    {
      month: 6,
      monthly: 102.72,
      interest: 24.36,
      cost: 616.32,
      total: 591.96
    },
    {
      month: 12,
      monthly: 53.15,
      interest: 24.36,
      cost: 616.32,
      total: 591.96
    }
  ];

  return (
    <ul className="monthly-instalments">
      {creditValues.map(creditValue => (
        <li
          className={setActive ? "active" : "notactive"}
          data-month={creditValue.month}
          data-interval={creditValue.interval}
          data-apr={creditValue.apr}
          data-monthly={creditValue.monthly}
          data-interest={creditValue.interest}
          data-cost={creditValue.cost}
          data-total={creditValue.total}
          onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
        >
          {creditValue.month} months
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-hofstadter-7rgz5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current example, both list items share the same state.

Therefore, on each render, toggling the state will reflect both `<li/>` items.

You want each list item to have its own `active` state.

Note that you have some bugs like string `'false'`, comparing the `className` with `setActive` function and not having the `noactive` CSS class.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const creditValues = [
  {
    month: 6,
    monthly: 102.72,
    interest: 24.36,
    cost: 616.32,
    total: 591.96,
  },
  {
    month: 12,
    monthly: 53.15,
    interest: 24.36,
    cost: 616.32,
    total: 591.96,
  },
];

const Item = ({ children }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li
      className={active ? 'active' : 'noactive'}
      onClick={() => setActive(p => !p)}
    >
      {children}
    </li>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ul className="monthly-instalments">
      {creditValues.map((creditValue, index) => (
        <Item key={index}>{creditValue.month} months</Item>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit cold-brook-tsdrs]

Comment: Its a [functional `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Ok - (p => !p) - it's change from true to false.